# Root Crontab say command not found in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

Currently I am writing a little script which should add a cronjob to the root crontable. But it seems that my root crontable stopped working. When I try to run the crontab commands in my bash scrip, I get "command not found". Also it worked for some time and stopped working yesterday. Now when I enter "sudo crontab -l" I don't get "no crontab for root" anymore. I am not sure what I did wrong. Here is my code:

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo crontab -l > rootcron 2> /dev/null
sudo echo "test" >> rootcron
sudo crontab rootcron
sudo rm rootcron
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify when the command is to be run. Typically you would see something like:

```
*/5 * * * * touch /tmp/test-cron
```

So basically you probably have an invalid cron file. What are the contents of the file now?